# Display all nodes with actually viewed taxonomy term

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, views

I have an taxonomy term.

I want to display all nodes that has this term assigned just under the taxonomy term description.

So when user goes to page with the taxonomy he can see the description (that works by default) but also e.g. teasers of all nodes that has this term in field. I guess I have to somehow use view with some filter, but I cannot get it working.

I added the view with block that I've put into structure -> block layout.

I can display all the nodes that has `field1` set to `term A` by adding (to view) Filter criteria `field1 = term A`. But this is "hardcoded" and I need `term A` to be another term based on which term page am I visiting.

For example, when I visit page of `term A` I want to display all nodes that has `field1` set to `term A`. But when I look for `term B` page, I want to list all nodes with `field1 = term B` in my view.

Comment: You need a contextual filter. The default view for terms has one already *admin/structure/views/view/taxonomy_term*. You could make a block out of this view and I think the result is what you've described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a default view related to taxonomy term u can make use of it and change accordingly it will solve ur problem.